# Run-time error '5': trying to import query table from web

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a project for class and I am trying to import a fantasy football query table from the site www.thehuddle.com. I am trying to write the code in VBA instead of using excel tools for a higher degree of difficulty and the ability to use the refresh method.

When I run the code and use the debugger I get "run-time error '5'". Can anyone seem to see why? I cannot find an invalid procedure or I do not have enough knowledge to spot it.

```
Dim shtQBs As Worksheet, shtRBs As Worksheet, shtWRs As Worksheet, shtTEs As Worksheet
Dim shtDs As Worksheet, shtSTs As Worksheet, shtKs As Worksheet

Set shtQBs = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_project.xlsm").Worksheets("QBs")
Set shtRBs = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_project.xlsm").Worksheets("RBs")
Set shtWRs = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_project.xlsm").Worksheets("WRs")
Set shtTEs = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_project.xlsm").Worksheets("TEs")
Set shtDs = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_project.xlsm").Worksheets("Ds")
Set shtSTs = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_project.xlsm").Worksheets("STs")
Set shtKs = Application.Workbooks("auco6215_project.xlsm").Worksheets("Ks")

shtQBs.Activate

 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://www.thehuddle.com/stats/2014/plays_std.php?ccs=6&pos=qb", _
    Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "plays_std.php?ccs=6&pos=qb"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Cheers

Comment: What line is the error happening on?  Your With statement is probably the problem. It seems like you should separate the actual .Add from the With.  I am not sure though.

Comment: I switched it to: "with ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add....." and now it is giving me an error in the line ".commandType = 0

Comment: I may be way off here, but since you are using 'With xxxx" and have included the '.Add' method in that 'With', you maybe should say "With ActiveSheet" then new line of ".QueryTables..." then new line of ".CommandType".....

Comment: It runs for me without the `CommandType = 0` line, but I'm not sure why. Excel 2010.

Comment: @DougGlancy Same here and I am not too sure why. Now I am getting a different error when I am trying to run it for the running back position, something that the range isn't the same as the detestation. Also, since I got it to work, every time I open the workbook (since it is an event procedure) it reloads the data starting in P1

Comment: I don't see why you would recreate these every time you open. Instead, set up the workbook and just refresh them when it opens.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I commented out the line ".commandtype = 0" but now I am getting a "run-time error: sub-scropt out of range" for my second sheet. Can anyone see why?

```
With Sheets("QBs").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.thehuddle.com/stats/2014/plays_std.php?ccs=6&pos=qb", _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        '.CommandType = 0
        .Name = "plays_std.php?ccs=6&pos=qb"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With



    With Sheets("RBs").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://www.thehuddle.com/stats/2014/plays_std.php?ccs=6&pos=rb", _
        Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "plays_std.php?ccs=6&pos=rb"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```